# Mac OS Mac Ports deleted bash (no command line available)

Tags: bash, macos, shell, macports

I've upgraded my Mac OS, and have been now following [these instructions](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration) to upgrade my Mac Ports too. After I deleted all installed ports (step 3.c) my terminal app suddenly stopped responding. I've spent quite some time trying to decrypt what's happened, and I now believe that this is because I had `/opt/local/bin/bash` installed via Mac Ports, and this is now uninstalled ... So, when launching the Terminal or iTerm2 app, the apps simply crash not being able to find bash (I think, it's very difficult to understand any of this from the logs that Mac OS makes avail in the Console app).

So with all this, and command line not working, how can I undo the harm? Was thinking about somehow telling Terminal/iTerm2 to use another shell (for the time until I will have reinstalled bash over Mac Ports)? I assume there's something like `ksh` installed on my Mac by default? But how would I do that?

Comment: You _can't_ delete `/bin/bash` on MacOS Big Sur -- it's always there no matter what MacPorts does. So use that one instead of messing with `/opt/local/bin/bash` at all. You can indeed tell your terminal to invoke a different shell from the one your user account is configured for; in iTerm2 (my preferred terminal) it's under "Profiles".

Comment: That said, Stack Overflow is only for questions about writing software. This is a better fit for [apple.se], [unix.se], or [Super User](https://superuser.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Answering Community Wiki because the question is off-topic here.</sub>

---

#### In Apple's Terminal

Go to Terminal > Preferences > Profiles > Shell; check "Run command"; enter `/bin/bash -li`; uncheck "Run inside shell"; and then open a new window or tab.

---

#### In iTerm2

Go to Profiles -> Open Profiles -> Edit Profiles...; under "Command" change from the default of "Login Shell" to "Custom Shell", and enter `/bin/bash`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate! Saved my day! Terminal would simply crash, not allowing me to access any setting, but iTerm2 thing did help!